# Unlock password when reboot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, password, reboot

Every time I reboot the computer I got question to unlock the disk.
Is it possible to remove this? The computer is used by several people and
I don't want to give out the `root` password.

Comment: That could be at bios, boot, or encryption level. You need to give more details to have a useful answer...

Comment: I think its at the encrypting level.

Answer (score 1):

About Ubuntu only...

If it really is full system disk encryption (**dm-crypt/LUKS/cryptsetup** style) then there is no quick or easy way to remove the encryption. Maybe start up & decrypt, copy unencrypted info to new disks as a new "system", then run the new system only, but that's about the same as reinstalling, and harder than just using a live cd/usb to reinstall from scratch.

If you're talking about user-level encryption (**eCryptfs**) with just an encrypted home directory, you could set up new users (possibly with no encryption) and their own login password. Using `adduser` or `useradd` or gui user/group tools could do that.

A BIOS password just to boot would have to be given out or removed, but there should the ability to set a different password for changing BIOS settings.